# Live stream Text-To-Speech audio

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, audio, obs

**Goal**: To play an audio file generated by TTS, at the same time as animating a characters mouth.

**Background**: While streaming to Twitch I have several illustrated characters. Viewers can make one of the characters talk by triggering a command that uses the characters name; ie "!norman This mead tastes funny". this sends the text to googles-TTS and creates an mp3. In the past I've run a script that automatically plays the file on my PC through VLC player. But now I want to add an animated mouth to each character that moves "in sync"(looking into Forced Alignment for better sync). I want to use a browser source in OBS to overlay the mouth on top of the character.

**Node Modules**: phonemify, express, ejs, cors, @twurple, @google-cloud/text-to-speech

**Blocker**:
Audio files require me to manually press the play button as soon as the new mp3 is created. and even then it will often just play the cached file instead of fetching the new version of output.mp3. I need the new file to play automatically as soon as it's created.

**proposed solution**: (but open to suggestions)
After much reading I suspect that the solution is to have an audio element(client side) that points at a m3u8 file. Then from the server take the newly created mp3 and add it to the m3u8 play list. My assumption is that this will make the client automatically play the audio. But I can't figure out how to do this part.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const phonemify = require('phonemify');
const path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');
const visemify = require(path.join(__dirname + `/public/visemify.js`));
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
const util = require('util');
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
const cors = require('cors'); // SSE
const { StaticAuthProvider } = require('@twurple/auth');
const { ChatClient } = require('@twurple/chat');

let clients = []; // SSE
let phrases = []; // SSE
let streamClients = []; // Stream

app.set(`view engine`, `ejs`);
app.set(`views`, path.join(__dirname + `/views`));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors()); // SSE

const clientId = '##############################';
const accessToken = '############################';
const authProvider2 = new StaticAuthProvider(clientId, accessToken, ['chat:read', 'chat:edit', 'channel:moderate']);
const chatClient = new ChatClient({ authProvider2, channels: ['bingo_bob'] });
chatClient.connect();
const commandListener = chatClient.onMessage(async (channel, user, message, msg) => {
    const REGnorman = /^!norman+./i;
    if(REGnorman.test(message)){
       const phrase = message.replace(REGnorman, "");
       loader(phrase);
       const load = loader(phrase);
        clients.forEach(client => client.response.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(load.vis)}\n\n`))
    }
});

app.get('/events', eventsHandler); // SSE
app.get('/stream', streamHandler); // Stream
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if(req.query.phrase){
    const phrase = req.query.phrase;
    const load = loader(phrase);
    res.render(`index`, { load: load });
    }
    res.render(`index`, { load: [{ vis: 21 }] }); 
});
function loader(phrase){ // Phonemify & Visemify
    const load = {};
    const text1 = phonemify(phrase);
    const re = /\s+/;
    const text2 = text1.split(re).join('-');
    const re2 = /\d/g;
    const text3 = text2.replaceAll(re2, '-');
    const re3 = /\W+/;
    const text4 = text3.split(re3);
    load.pho = text4
    load.vis = visemify(load.pho);
    quickStart(phrase);
    return load;
}
async function quickStart(phrase) { // Google-TTS
    const text = phrase;
    const request = {
        input: { text: text },
        voice: { languageCode: "en-GB", name: "en-GB-Wavenet-D", ssmlGender: 'MALE' },
        audioConfig: { audioEncoding: 'MP3', speakingRate: "1.0", pitch: "-4.0", effectsProfileId: ["large-home-entertainment-class-device"] }
    };
    const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
    const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
    await writeFile(path.join(__dirname + `/public/audio/output.mp3`), response.audioContent, 'binary');
    console.log('Audio content written to file: output.mp3',phrase);
}
function eventsHandler(request, response, next) { // SSE
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    };
    response.writeHead(200, headers);
    const data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(phrases)}\n\n`;
    response.write(data);
    const clientId = Date.now();
    const newClient = {
      id: clientId,
      response
    };
    clients.push(newClient);
    request.on('close', () => {
      console.log(`${clientId} Connection closed`);
      clients = clients.filter(client => client.id !== clientId);
    });
  }
function streamHandler(req,res,next) { // Stream
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type':'audio/mp3',
        'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    const audioPath = path.join(__dirname + `/public/audio/output.mp3`);
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(audioPath);
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + `/public/audio/output.mp3`));
    // res.send(readStream);
    // res.write(readStream);
    const clientId = Date.now();
    const newClient = {
        id: clientId,
        res
    };
    streamClients.push(newClient);
    req.on('close', () => {
        console.log(`${clientId} Connection closed`);
        streamClients = clients.filter(client => client.id !== clientId);
    });
}
app.listen(3000)
```

**index.ejs**

```
  <!-- omitted animated mouth -->
<audio id="audioStream" controls src="/audio/norman.m3u8"></audio>
<script src="/script.js"></script>
```

**script.js**

```
// omitted animated mouth functions
const evtSource = new EventSource(`http://localhost:3000/events`); // SSE
evtSource.onmessage = function(event) { // SSE
    const newElement = document.createElement("li");
    const eventList = document.getElementById("list");
    newElement.textContent = `message: ${event.data}`;
    eventList.appendChild(newElement);
    visemes = JSON.parse(event.data);
    runMouth(visemes);
  }
  const mp3Source = new EventSource(`http://localhost:3000/stream`); // Stream
  mp3Source.onmessage = function(event) { // Stream
    const audioStream = document.getElementById("audioStream");
    audioStream.src = `${event.data}`;
    console.log(event.data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this was my solution. I still have to refactor and make adjustments. But this is really what I was looking for.

```js
_sinks = new Map();
app.get('/stream', (req,res)=>{
  const { id, responseSink } = makeResponseSink();
  req.app.sinkId = id;
  res.set('Content-Type','audio/mpeg');
  responseSink.pipe(res);
});
function makeResponseSink() {
  const id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
  const responseSink = PassThrough();
  _sinks.set(id, responseSink);
  return { id, responseSink };
};
function startStreaming(){
  const currentSong = readDir().filter(isMp3)[0].name;
  const bitRate = getBitRate(currentSong);
  const songReadable = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname + `/public/audio/`,currentSong));
  const throttleTransformable = new Throttle(bitRate);
  throttleTransformable.on('data', (chunk) => {broadcastToEverySink(chunk);});
  throttleTransformable.on('end', () => playLoop());
  songReadable.pipe(throttleTransformable);
}
const readDir = () => fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname + `/public/audio/`), { withFileTypes: true });
const isMp3 = item => item.isFile && extname(item.name) === '.mp3';
function getBitRate(song) {
  try {
      const bitRate = ffprobeSync(path.join(__dirname + `/public/audio/`,song)).format.bit_rate;
      return parseInt(bitRate);
  }
  catch (err) {
      return 128000; // reasonable default
  }
};
function broadcastToEverySink(chunk) {
  for (const [, sink] of _sinks) {
      sink.write(chunk);
  }
}
function playLoop(){
  startStreaming();
}
startStreaming();
```